# Python Socket - Server side - Cursor is stuck at conn.receive(1024)

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I am new to socket programming. I was able to communicate between 2 system with socket communication. But suddenly started facing this issue. Connection is getting established and accepted but when cursor reaches conn.receive(1024) it is stuck at this point. I am not getting neither data nor any error. Can anyone suggest what is going wrong? What are the possible system settings might affect the code? Not able to figure out whether issue is at server or client side.

```
    import socket
    HOST = ''
    PORT = 2048

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print('Socket created')

    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    print('Socket bind complete')

    s.listen(10)
    print('Socket now listening')
    while True:
       conn, addr = s.accept()
       # Retrieve message size
       data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
```

Comment: Maybe you need to flush. I always flush() after a read()

Comment: Hi Shashank, welcome to SO, to help people answer your question are you able to provide the snippet of code you are working on?

Comment: If I am right at understanding are you asking to use flush() at client side after sending the data?

Comment: @mama: There is no such thing in python sockets, but even if there were flushing is something that is done after a write, not a read.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot. But there is, and I use it after writing then.

Comment: Your code is waiting for some data to be received and it isn't getting any.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yes

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer!!!!!!!. Since the client side was in java it was seen that flush() command was not used. Once flush() command added it started working.

Thanks for the hint @mama